# Creating a fuction for train_test from tuple

Tags: python, statistics

Can somebody help me how to solve this?

I have to create a function that has tuple(X,y) as parameter, that splits 70% for training and 30% for validation and that at the end return a tuple (X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test) where X_train and X_test are DataFrame type and y_train,y_test are Series

thanks a lot

Comment: Do not invent the wheel, just use sklearn. Regards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.